# Update one product with good performance

Tags: performance, magento

I was wondering why an update of each product was taking 10s per product!
even without updating anything, just by pressing the "save" button.

I found that there is an observer on product_save_after
name is: applyAllRulesOnProduct

So even if you don't change the price, it applies all your promotion on this product!
And not only, it also updates all the quotes!
The latter was taking around 2s, and this was done 4 times per update!
Here is the query:

```
UPDATE `sales_flat_quote` AS `t1`
 INNER JOIN (SELECT `t2`.`quote_id` AS `entity_id` FROM `sales_flat_quote_item`     AS `t2`
INNER JOIN `catalogrule_product_price` AS `t3`
 WHERE (t2.product_id = t3.product_id) GROUP BY `quote_id`) AS `t2` ON t1.entity_id     =     t2.entity_id
SET `t1`.`trigger_recollect` = 1"
```

I am wondering why it does such thing, updating all quotes without update of price?
I call this a bug.
Magento should check which field has been updated...

BTW the sales_flate_quote table is never emptied by magento, even if I have configure automatic cleaning of logs.
So one "solution" was to remove all quotes done more than 5 days ago:
    DELETE FROM sales_flat_quote WHERE updated_at < DATE_SUB(Now(),INTERVAL 5 DAY)

This reduced drastically the duration of the query.
0.3s!

Now, I am wondering if some of you found another solution.
I was thinking about removing the observer, and doing a daily refresh of the Rules (promotions).
Side effect is that the update of the price is not reflected by the promotion immediately.

Another solution would be to run this in the background.
I've bought Magento Embedded ERP and it has a concept of background task , I will check if I can plug this one on top of the ERP task. So when I save a product, a task is created in the background to run "applyAllRulesOnProduct"

Note that there is 30 000 products in my DB, I synchronize the price with supplier on a daily basis.
before it was 10s per update, fortunately only few products have a price that change on a daily basis, otherwise it would have taken 10*30000/3600= more than 2 days :-)

thanks about any help about making a product update shorter.

Rod

Comment: I believe you have very old hardware or server is loaded with something else. Because we don't have such big product save time. I believe it is around 1 sec or less.

Comment: my config:Bi-Opteron AMD Quad-Core 2350,
8 GB RAM,
HD 2 x 240 Go SSD Intel 520
.Os : Mandriva 2010.2 . Do you think it's a bad server ? :-) It's a full SSD dedicated server. Cache is enabled, and var folder is in RAM (session, cache etc)! It needs 10 s to update a product because it has to update the quotes, and there are a lot of quotes. But it's useless to update the old quotes when you just change the description for instance

Answer (score 0):

You can disable relate events by:

```
$product->setIsMassupdate(true);
$product->setExcludeUrlRewrite(true);
```